# Parse Error - Installing apk programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent, android-emulator, apk

I am trying to install an apk file programmatically. I referred this [site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4967669/android-install-apk-programmatically) for doing it.

Now the apk file is downloaded from an url and placed in SDCard. When I try to install it on the device using Intent method,

It is popping up following error

Emulator:

```
 "Parse Error - There is a problem parsing the package",
Logcat(W) : "Unable to read AndroidManifest.xml of /mnt/sdcard/download/myapp.apk",
Logcat(W) : "java.ioException: AndroidManifest.xml",
Logcat(W) : "Parse error when parsing manifest. Discontinuing installation".
Logcat(E) : "java.lang.SecurityException",
Logcat(E) : "java.lang.NullPointerException".
```

Note: 1) I was able to install the same .apk file using adb.
      2) I changed this .apk file to .pdf format before sending it to Server Team and then they changed it back to .apk. I am adding this coz there might be chances for error due to format conversion.

Comment: Looks like a problem with your APK. Check if you can download it from the server and install the downloaded file through adb.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rajesh, I will do it and keep you posted :)

Comment: Whoops: didn't find expected signature, read_centraldirectory_entry_failed, file 'C:\APK\MyApp.apk' is not a valid zip file. this is what I got in cmd when I tried to install but when I installed the apk in the project/bin/ I was able to install the application.

Comment: Something is messing up with your APK, possibly in the PDF <-> APK conversion process.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rajesh. I loaded the apk file manually on the sdcard and tried, but no luck, it is showing the same error. :(

Answer (score 1):

Installation can give the specified error at least in following cases:

- **Name of the package is changed after signing:** Use the exact name as
  the signed package is (instead, adjust the name in Manifest)
- **Package    is compiled against on higher API level:** Correct the API
  level in    Manifest file
- **Package is executed from SD-card:** Run    (install) the apk    -file
  from phones memory OR use adb command to    install it

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code

```
  private void installApk(){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File("/sdcard/path"));
                            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
                            startActivity(intent);}
```